# Who is the "creature" in the final verses of this poem?

Tags: interpretation, elinor-wylie

Elinor Wylie's poem [*The Mountaineer's Ballad*](https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/mountaineers-ballad) ends with the following two-and-a-half verses, which describe the eponymous mountaineer:

> Thinking maybe of marriages,
> And maybe of wars.
>
> And maybe of the creature
> That runs at his heel,
> Clad in rough velvet
> And shod with smooth steel;
>
> That runs forever at his right hand
> Like a sleek lightning-flash,
> And he with nothing to defend him
> But a rawhide lash.

What is this creature?

If it's the Devil, why is he wearing horseshoes (if these are indeed what are on his feet)? Horseshoes are generally antithetical to the Devil in folklore.

And if it's not the Devil, what is it?

Comment: I don't think "shod" implies horseshoes, just footwear.

Comment: @tgdavies: It's the "smooth steel" part that I think implies horseshoes. But maybe there are other kinds of steel shoes.

Comment: I think of horseshoes as being roughly wrought. Flippantly, I'm going to say the creature is a railway passenger carriage!